# How to get the nearest class of separate div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On clicking the button I want to get the closest `<input name="something/>` value.

I tried `$(this).closest(".input").val()` but didn't work.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
  div = `<div class="second-div"><input name="something/></div>
         <div class="third-div"></div>`
         
  // get nearest <input name="something/> value
  // get nearest <input class="a-input" /> value
  
  $(".main-div").append(div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="second-div">
    <input name="something" class="input" />
  </div>
  <div class="third-div">
    <input name="another input" class="a-input" />
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-div">
    <button type="button" class="button">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `closest` traverses upwards in the DOM. The input element is not an ancestor of the button. You need to traverse up to the `.main-div` first, and from there select downwards again, f.e. using `find`.

Comment: [Traversing | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Comment: @CBroe I tried `console.log($(this).closest('main-div').find('.input').val()) but result is undefined.
`

Comment: `.closest('.main-div')`

Comment: @CBroe it worked only once but not for added dom with click events

Comment: I don't know what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: @CBroe Inside `main-div` there can be n numbers of  input with class `input` so I want to get only last added input value.

Comment: Well then you need to actually select the last of those input fields first. Read access via `.val()` only ever gets you the value of the first element in the selection.

Comment: @CBroe i don't know how can I do this ? Can you post a demo answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would traverse up to the containing div first, then back down to the desired control.

```
$(this).closest(".main-div").find(".input");
```

**EDIT**

I just read your comment saying you want to get the last instance of a class.

```
$(this).closest(".main-div").find(".input").last();
```

**EXAMPLE**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
  div = `<div class="second-div"><input name="something" class="input"/></div>
         <div class="third-div"></div>`
         
  $(".input").removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).closest(".main-div").find(".input").last().addClass("highlight");
  // get nearest <input name="something/> value
  // get nearest <input class="a-input" /> value
  
  $(".main-div").append(div);
});
```

```css
.highlight{
  background:#b00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
  <div class="second-div">
    <input name="something" class="input" />
  </div>
  <div class="third-div">
    <input name="another input" class="a-input" />
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-div">
    <button type="button" class="button">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```